# detect url and redirect to another if equal .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

The site can be accessed with a subdomain and a domain:

> username.freesite.com

How do I redirect *all requests* made to `username.freesite.com` to redirect to `mysite.com`? (Both urls point to the same A address).

Comment: Please add some example of urls and what you want them to redirect to.

Comment: If you can't bother to give a few examples, I don't see why I should try to help you. In your question you say you want to redirect to mysite.com, but the rewriterule contain site.com. You talk about `v1` without explaining what it is.

Comment: it's a typo, i fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

Enable mod_rewrite and .htaccess through `httpd.conf` and then put this code in your `.htaccess` under `DOCUMENT_ROOT` directory:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^[^.]+\.(freesite\.com)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://%1%{REQUEST_URI} R=302,L]
```

PS: This will also redirect `www.freesite.com` to `freesite.com`. Let me know if you want an exception for `www.freesite.com`.